# Not able to import models in views.py #python #django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

[**This happens when I try to rn server**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY4kf.png%60%60)

[This photo describes the project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReJHI.png)
**Django - Python**

---

### views.py

***Just*** when I try to import "Post" model, I have this error and I can't reach any page.
If I don't import any model in views.py everything looks good..
Could you help me to fix this issue?

```
from .models import Post
def home_view(request):
    latest_posts = Post.objects.order_by('pub_date')[:3]
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'Latest': latest_posts})
```

---

### models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    brief_life = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    Date_of_birth = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10000)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    copy_num = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    for_buy = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=True)
    p_type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

---

### apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class PostsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'posts'
```

---

### settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'posts',
]



MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'
```

---

### url.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from src.posts.views import home_view, about_view, details_view, post_info_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
    path('about/', about_view, name='about'),
    path('details/', details_view, name='details'),
    path('info/', post_info_view, name='info'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Did you add the app name (here `'posts'`) to the `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py` file?

Comment: Yes I added it to **settings.py** and everything works right but when I try to import my model in **views.py** it gives me that error.<br/>

Comment: This is INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py:
`
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'posts',
]`
@WillemVanOnsem

Comment: is your `views.py` in same directory ? try `from posts.models import Post`

Comment: I tried it, but nothing changed @PankajSharma

Comment: What about your `urls.py`? what do you have in there?

Comment: @CarlBrubaker 
I can reach any page before importing the model to views.py. <br/> Post edited and you can see **url.py**

Comment: Have you tried commenting out your `Author` model and relations to it to see if the error changes?

Comment: @CarlBrubaker Yes have tried it and run **migrate** the error message changed when I removed **Author** and **Type** models from **models.py**. the new message  `File "C:\Users\Mohannad Raslan\dev\v_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 108, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class src.posts.models.Post doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `ForeignKey` `on_delete` set up wrong. `True` is not a valid option. Refer to the [Model Field reference ForeignKey field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) to set a valid option. If you want to delete when foreign key is removed, use `models.CASCADE`

Also, your installed app is `posts`. In your `urls` you are `import`ing `from src.posts.views`. Try getting rid of the `src.` and it should fix your problem.

Comment: I still have the same error message: "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class src.posts.models.Author doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Did you run your migration?

Comment: yes, I deleted all migration files and execute `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate` but I still have the same problem when adding `from .models import Post` to **views.py** file.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by removing the spaces by tabs in code beautifying and its working